# Can someone help me understand this case regarding the work done by normal force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, work

I’ve encountered this problem in Giancoli Physics practice problems, and I can’t seem to understand why the normal force does zero work despite that there is vertical displacement as the cart moves up the ramp.

I attach below the problem with the free body diagram associated with it.

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Here , normal force is not vertical. So you have to look for displacement in direction of force not vertically.

Comment: @VedantChhapariya totally correct, but I can take a component of the normal force such that it becomes parallel to the displacement, essentially by Fncosx, am I right?

Comment: @DoePual Sure, you could calculate the work done by the vertical component of the normal force. But that will be balanced out by the negative work done by the horizontal component. Together, the normal force as a whole does no work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work done by a force is defined as a scalar product of force and displacement vectors:

$$\boxed{W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x}}$$

The scalar product between two vectors is defined as

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |\vec{a}| |\vec{b}| \cos\alpha = a_i b_i + a_j b_j$$

where $\alpha$ is angle between the two vectors.

Since normal force is always perpendicular to the displacement (motion), the scalar product will be zero and the work done by normal force is zero.

To show this mathematically, you first need to setup a coordinate system. Remember that you can define the coordinate system in any way you want, as long as axis are perpendicular. In your example the coordinate system is defined such that normal force lies along $\hat{\jmath}$ axis and motion happens along $\hat{\imath}$ axis, hence the scalar product is zero:

$$(1\hat{\imath} + 0\hat{\jmath}) \cdot (0\hat{\imath} + 1\hat{\jmath}) = 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 1 = 0$$

You could also define the coordinate system such that gravitational force lies along $\hat{\jmath}$ axis in which case both displacement and normal force would have both $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ components. However, their scalar product would still be zero! Try to solve your example for this coordinate system. You don’t even have to include forces in the calculation, just do the scalar product with unit vectors for displacement and normal force.

Comment: Is the distance you are referring to the “displacement” vector? If so, can we use the vertical displacement in work calculations with respect to the normal force present here?

Comment: You cannot look only at vertical displacement and forget about horizontal displacement, that is why we have scalar product. It multiplies both axis and then sums them together. See again definition for scalar product.

Comment: Oh I see, and just to be sure, the displacement vector that we take into account in scalar product calculations is the displacement along the axis where motion occurs, am I right here?

Comment: Exactly. So if you rotate the coordinate system, the displacement vector also rotates. In your example the coordinate system is chosen such that displacement points along one axis because the equations are nicer in that case.

Comment: I think this explains why we shouldn’t consider the vertical component.

Comment: Thank you @markogulin! Much appreciated!

Comment: In your example there is no "vertical displacement" if you define vertical to be along $\hat{\jmath}$ axis. In other example there is vertical displacement and it needs to be taken into account together with horizontal displacement when calculating work. Scalar product formula always works, it is the fundamental part of the work definition.